# libhardware.so is failing to load in Android N. Is this due to new Android N policies?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-7.0-nougat

My app uses libhardware.so from android system/lib. It is a native app. upto Android M It's working fine but when try to run it with Android N. It is showing dlopen failed library libhardware.so not found.

Recently I came across this article https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk

Cause of failure is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so. You should use libraries provided with your app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The list of libraries that you're able to load from the system is https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/cc508145a36939c74399a90b9092673cf54e67f4/build/core/build-binary.mk#61

```
system_libs := \
    android \
    c \
    dl \
    jnigraphics \
    log \
    m \
    m_hard \
    stdc++ \
    z \
    EGL \
    GLESv1_CM \
    GLESv2 \
    GLESv3 \
    vulkan \
    OpenSLES \
    OpenMAXAL \
    mediandk \
    atomic
```

Comment: to be exact, the list is available in docs with minimum API available: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html

Comment: That doc is out of date though. It only goes up to 21, but there were new APIs added in 23 and 24.

Comment: Hi dan,

Right now my app is using libhardware.so. Is there any way I can ask my app to switch to its own copy of libhardware.so? I tried to bundle the libhardware.so in /data/data/<app>/lib/libhardware.so but still it is failing.

Comment: adding further info that my project doesnot have android.mk file. I use "android update project" command.

Comment: libhardware also depends on a handful of libraries that aren't in the NDK (this is going to be true of every system library). If you've taken libhardware.so off an android device or from an aosp build, you're still going to have that problem. logcat should be printing the information you need.

Comment: Added all the libraries needed by libhardware solved my issue.

Comment: @shreya_s7 did you just put all LIBs from /system/lib/hw to your /data/data/project/lib folder? Did you put hw as subfolder or just copied all libs from hw directly to .../project/lib?

Comment: @MaximMetelskiy I just copied libhardware.so to /data/data/project/lib/.

Comment: @shreya_s7 I get it, but what did you do with libs from which libhardware.so depends?

Comment: @MaximMetelskiy I need to get hardware module for testing. After changes some of my code still failing as libhardware indirectly calling gralloc.<aarch>.so Currrently I am trying solve this issue. Please let me know If you any details regarding this.

Comment: @shreya_s7 The best solution will be to avoid using private libs) But you can try to rebuild libhardware.so from AOSP. It searches for hardware libs using absolute paths, and you can modify sources to add your app's directory in search list. And also add all required hardware libs to your project. But it's very unstable solution, because different devices may have different hardware libs. You can also try to install your app as system application using root access, then it would be able to load private system libs. But it also very unstable solution.